# Is static_cast<int>(long long) safe?

Tags: c++, casting

Is `static_cast<int>(long long)` safe (guaranteed behavior)?

Or I should `static_cast<int>(val & 0xffffffffLL)` first?

Comment: Beware the 64 bit `int`.

Comment: Define safe! It won't crash, but you may lose information.

Answer (score 2):

It is safe, however, it may be implementation defined.

First,

> 4.8 Integral conversions [**[conv.integral]**](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.integral#3)
>
> *1* **A prvalue of an integer type can be converted to a prvalue of
>   another integer type**. A prvalue of an unscoped enumeration type can
>   be converted to a prvalue of an integer type.
>
> *3* If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can
>   be represented in the destination type; **otherwise, the value is
>   implementation-defined.**

Now,

> 3.9.1 Fundamental types **[[basic.fundamental]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.fundamental#2)**
>
> *2* There are five standard signed integer types : `signed char`, `short int`, `int`, `long int`, and `long long int`. In this list,
>   each type provides at least as much storage as those preceding it in
>   the list. There may also be implementation-defined extended signed
>   integer types. The standard and extended signed integer types are
>   collectively called signed integer types. Plain ints have the natural
>   size suggested by the architecture of the execution
>   environment<sup>46</sup>; the other signed integer types are provided
>   to meet special needs.
>
> <sub>*46)* `int` must also be large enough to contain any value in
>   the range `[INT_MIN, INT_MAX]`, as defined in the header
>   `<climits>`.</sub>

Which means, that `long long` is as least as big as `int`. If they are of same size, conversion between them does nothing. If `long long` is bigger, it is implementation defined, but I've never seen an implementation, which would do something else other than taking first `n` bytes according to size.

Comment: "I've never seen an implementation, which would do something else other than taking first `n` bytes according to size." -- It's the most natural result for two's complement implementations, which are by far the most common. I suspect if any implementation behaves differently, it'll be one of the ones that don't use 2C.

Comment: @hvd: It is actually broader than that: "If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can be represented in the destination type". Anyone insist on the "otherwise side" since it contains the word "undefined" (the -for reason I'll never be able to understand, triggers unjustified red alarms in many brainwashed people), but the main statement is this one: whatever representation of number you use, if "-5" exist in both types, -5 must remain -5.

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia Sure, but I don't see where I or anyone else claimed otherwise. It just so happens that in 2C, the most natural way of doing that is by dropping the high-value bits, without looking at whether the value is out of range.